# Postfix Using Gmail Relay: Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: postfix, gmail, smtp

I get this error: **Must issue a STARTTLS command first** with all sent mail.

Can anyone see why?

main.cf:

```
relayhost=[smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_connection_cache_destinations= [smtp.gmail.com]:587

#TLS parameters
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
# SASL Configuration
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_enforce_tls = no
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

tls_policy

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 encrypt
```

sasl_passwd

```
smtp.gmail.com:587 name@gmail.com:password
```

And, yes, I have run postmap on all the data files and have reloaded postfix after making changes.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

You should use `smtp_enforce_tls = yes`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your postfix tries to issue `AUTH` **before** issuing `STARTTLS` (-> it does not issue `STARTTLS`). AFAIK Gmail offers SMTP AUTH on ports 25 and 587 only after STARTTLS.

Have you restarted postfix daemon after adding `smtp_use_tls=yes`?

http://mhawthorne.net/posts/postfix-configuring-gmail-as-relay.html

Comment: you don't need to specify `smtp_use_tls=yes` if you use the policymap (as you seemingly have to with gmail)

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: No, a policy map for TLS encryption isn't compulsory to access Gmail services. It just specifies an optional lookup table ( viz. http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_policy_maps) . OP just uses them because he/she/it wants to.  Anyway  `smtp_use_tls=yes` is obsolete and superseded by `smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt`. OP could do without it.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that setting `smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt` in /etc/postfix.main.cf resolves this issue.